# Gradle build - compileJava Error - no access to detailed error

Tags: maven, gradle, build, compiler-errors, pf4j

Im building a java application using the pf4j plugin framework with gradle as the build service. Initially everything worked great. Since I migrated to a new machine with a JDK10 and probably some other installations properties on gradle or whatever, the build failed. A "compileError" occured. Therefore,  I cloned and tried to build the pf4j demo project. Same error. Unfortunately, no matter what I try, I'm not able to see the inital compile error.

With mvn clean install  I see:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Demo Parent                                                        [pom]
[INFO] Demo Api                                                           [jar]
[INFO] Demo App                                                           [jar]
[INFO] Demo Plugins Parent                                                [pom]
[INFO] Demo Plugin #1                                                     [jar]
[INFO] Demo Plugin #2                                                     [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< org.pf4j.demo:pf4j-demo-parent >-------------------
[INFO] Building Demo Parent 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT                                [1/6]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ pf4j-demo-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ pf4j-demo-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:jar (default) @ pf4j-demo-parent ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.JavadocJar
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.<clinit> (AbstractJavadocMojo.java:178)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:488)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd (String.java:3107)
    at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1873)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.getJavaVersionAsFloat (SystemUtils.java:1133)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.<clinit> (SystemUtils.java:818)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.<clinit> (AbstractJavadocMojo.java:178)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:488)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call (InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext (InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get (InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Demo Parent 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT ......................... FAILURE [  1.915 s]
[INFO] Demo Api ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Demo App ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Demo Plugins Parent ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Demo Plugin #1 ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Demo Plugin #2 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.205 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-10T18:46:57+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:jar (default) on project pf4j-demo-parent: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:jar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8:jar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/2.8/maven-javadoc-plugin-2.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.3/maven-archiver-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-invoker/2.0.9/maven-invoker-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.3/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0/doxia-site-renderer-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0/doxia-core-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0/doxia-decoration-model-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0/doxia-module-apt-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0/doxia-module-fml-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.0/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.0/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.9.2/qdox-1.9.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0-alpha-1/plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/-/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.8/plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : begin 0, end 3, length 2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

With gradle (with and without eclipse) i get:

```
Note: class org.pf4j.processor.ExtensionAnnotationProcessor init
Note: class org.pf4j.processor.ExtensionAnnotationProcessor init
Note: Processing @interface org.pf4j.Extension
error: C:pf4j\demo_gradle\app\build\classes\java\main\META-INF\extensions.idx
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:114)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
```

What can I do?

Comment: If you are on JDK 10 than all the plugins you are using the Maven build are simply to old...there might be some issues coming from ..apart from that I would turn on checksum policy for Maven and delete the local cache and retry...

Comment: Wow. Thx. I already thought about switching back to jdk 8 yesterday, but decided, it would probably only cause additionally issues. But it solved the issue. Suddenly my project builds perfectly fine. Didnt try the pf4j demo yet, but expect the same. not suer however, whether i should switch the issue to solves, since this is still an existing bug.

Comment: Could you please which updates exactly helped..might be interesting for others...

Comment: I just switched back from jdk 10 to jdk 8_161